# Does my 5th level aura count for feat prerequisites?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature

I am aware that at 5th level, my character starts to exude an aura even if I am not a cleric or paladin, as per the spell [Detect Evil](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-evil/).

Does this mean as of 5th level, I count as having having an aura for the purpose of feat prerequisites? For example, the feat [Sacred Summons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/sacred-summons/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

Sacred Summons requires that you have the aura *class feature*, not merely that you have *an aura*.

Comment: Everybody has an aura, not everybody has the Aura class feature: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-rules/occult-skill-unlocks/#Read_Aura_Perception

Comment: @Wyrmwood Correct you are; fixed.

Comment: Is *class feature* ever given a proper definition or is the definition only ever implied? (Note that I'm not disputing the answer, but I am wondering if there's an ugly legal argument in its background.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan No idea. Could easily see that going either way.

Comment: @HeyICanChan that sounds like the "spellcasting class feature" question from 3.5 (aka "why can't I boost my Mystic Thaumaturge casting?").

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don't see that as an ugly legal argument-- a 'class feature' is a feature of a class.  The aura OP is asking about doesn't come from any particular class, and in fact many creatures have no classes at all and still have an aura.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet My thinking was that the worst kind of rules lawyer  could argue that because a creature that advances only by character levels in a *class* gains from those levels the aura *feature*, that dude could argue that an aura for such a creature *is*, in fact, a *class feature*. That is, of course, if a definition of *class feature* is *not* provided by the game. (Note that I'd *not* support such a rules lawyer in his quest, and I'd likely throw dice at the dude, but as a purely legalistic argument it might have merit.)